# "The value of the local variable SoundButton38 is not used" But I Want To Use It?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, variables, warnings

I'm new to programming, and I am programming in eclipse.

I am creating a simple soundboard, but I am getting the warning "The value of the local variable SoundButton38 is not used", but I want to use that variable.

SoundButton1-37 are working and do not have the error, but 38-63 do have the warning. I'm not sure what is causing it and why it is happening.

Here's a snippet of my code where the warning is coming up (35, 36 and 37 do not have the warning:

```
            Button SoundButton35 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound35);
            SoundButton35.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(35);

        }
    });
            Button SoundButton36 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound36);
            SoundButton36.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(36);

        }
            });

            Button SoundButton37 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound37);
            SoundButton35.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(37);

        }
    });

            Button SoundButton38 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound38);
            SoundButton35.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(38);

        }
    });
```

And here is the beginning of my code

```
package com.soundboardtest;

import com.soundboardtest.R;
import com.soundboardtest.SoundManager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Soundboard extends Activity {
    private SoundManager mSoundManager;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_soundboardtest);

    mSoundManager = new SoundManager();
    mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());
    mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.sound1);
    mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.sound2);
    mSoundManager.addSound(3, R.raw.sound3);
    mSoundManager.addSound(4, R.raw.sound4);
    mSoundManager.addSound(5, R.raw.sound5);
    mSoundManager.addSound(6, R.raw.sound6);
    mSoundManager.addSound(7, R.raw.sound7);
    mSoundManager.addSound(8, R.raw.sound8);
    mSoundManager.addSound(9, R.raw.sound9);
    mSoundManager.addSound(10, R.raw.sound10);
    mSoundManager.addSound(11, R.raw.sound11);
    mSoundManager.addSound(12, R.raw.sound12);
    mSoundManager.addSound(13, R.raw.sound13);
    mSoundManager.addSound(14, R.raw.sound14);
    mSoundManager.addSound(15, R.raw.sound15);
    mSoundManager.addSound(16, R.raw.sound16);
    mSoundManager.addSound(17, R.raw.sound17);
    mSoundManager.addSound(18, R.raw.sound18);
    mSoundManager.addSound(19, R.raw.sound19);
    mSoundManager.addSound(20, R.raw.sound20);
    mSoundManager.addSound(21, R.raw.sound21);
    mSoundManager.addSound(22, R.raw.sound22);
    mSoundManager.addSound(23, R.raw.sound23);
    mSoundManager.addSound(24, R.raw.sound24);
    mSoundManager.addSound(25, R.raw.sound25);
    mSoundManager.addSound(26, R.raw.sound26);
    mSoundManager.addSound(27, R.raw.sound27);
    mSoundManager.addSound(28, R.raw.sound28);
    mSoundManager.addSound(29, R.raw.sound29);
    mSoundManager.addSound(30, R.raw.sound30);
    mSoundManager.addSound(31, R.raw.sound31);
    mSoundManager.addSound(32, R.raw.sound32);
    mSoundManager.addSound(33, R.raw.sound33);
    mSoundManager.addSound(34, R.raw.sound34);
    mSoundManager.addSound(35, R.raw.sound35);
    mSoundManager.addSound(36, R.raw.sound36);
    mSoundManager.addSound(37, R.raw.sound37);
    mSoundManager.addSound(38, R.raw.sound38);
    mSoundManager.addSound(39, R.raw.sound39);
    mSoundManager.addSound(40, R.raw.sound40);
    mSoundManager.addSound(41, R.raw.sound41);
    mSoundManager.addSound(42, R.raw.sound42);
    mSoundManager.addSound(43, R.raw.sound43);
    mSoundManager.addSound(44, R.raw.sound44);
    mSoundManager.addSound(45, R.raw.sound45);
    mSoundManager.addSound(46, R.raw.sound46);
    mSoundManager.addSound(47, R.raw.sound47);
    mSoundManager.addSound(48, R.raw.sound48);
    mSoundManager.addSound(49, R.raw.sound49);
    mSoundManager.addSound(50, R.raw.sound50);
    mSoundManager.addSound(51, R.raw.sound51);
    mSoundManager.addSound(52, R.raw.sound52);
    mSoundManager.addSound(53, R.raw.sound53);
    mSoundManager.addSound(54, R.raw.sound54);
    mSoundManager.addSound(55, R.raw.sound55);
    mSoundManager.addSound(56, R.raw.sound56);
    mSoundManager.addSound(57, R.raw.sound57);
    mSoundManager.addSound(58, R.raw.sound58);
    mSoundManager.addSound(59, R.raw.sound59);
    mSoundManager.addSound(60, R.raw.sound60);
    mSoundManager.addSound(61, R.raw.sound61);
    mSoundManager.addSound(62, R.raw.sound62);
    mSoundManager.addSound(63, R.raw.sound63);
```

Thanks for your help, I was unable to find a good answer for this.

Comment: You have 64 times the same code for a button? Please learn the DRY principle. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only declared and initialized it not used it any where

```
Button SoundButton38 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound38);
```

You probably want

```
SoundButton38.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //  SoundButton38 not 35

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(38);

    }
});
```

Similarly

```
    SoundButton37.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(37);

    }
});
```

Comment: "SoundButton 38 Cannot Be Resolved" is the error I get if I use your code.

Why did the first 37 work but then 38 onward doesnt?

Comment: oh my gosh I typed it in wrong, it's fixed now. I'll give you best answer once it allows it

Comment: @user3121598 and look for any further typo errors and syntax errors just to make sure everything is right

Answer (score 1):

```
 Button SoundButton38 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound38);
            SoundButton35.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

Looks like a typo here, I think it should have been

```
 SoundButton38.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

Similiarly

```
 Button SoundButton37 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound37);
            SoundButton35.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

should have been

```
SoundButton37.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

Comment: I was wondering why #37 wasnt giving this warning... ???.. The same issue there as well..